# Exception thrown in Hibernate code, is it because of transactions?

Tags: hibernate, transactions

Everyone, I have the following code which works on multiple test systems but then fails on the production system with a `NullPointerException`. Hibernate returns null for an Object that is definitely in the database. I think this might be due to poor transaction management but I am not sure. Does anyone see an issue? The code below all uses a Hibernate wrapper object, 'db'. When 'db' was created a new Session was created from Hibernate's session factory, so only my code shown below uses that Session.

Gets a list of all valid IDs from the Request table. ID is the primary key field:

```
Criteria criteria = db.getSession().createCriteria(Request.class);
Criterion crit = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("status", "valid"));
criteria.add(crit).setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
List<Integer> results = (List<Integer>)criteria.list();
List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer id : results) idList.add(id);
```

The below code is what throws the NullPointerException. See the code comments in the catch block. The helper methods are shown further below:

```
for (Integer id : idList){
   Request current = null;
   try{
      current = (Request) db.getObj(Request.class, Restrictions.eq("id", id));
      // ... other business logic in here
      InvalidRequest newInvalidRequest = new InvalidRequest(current.getId(), current);
      db.addObject(newInvalidRequest);
    }
    } catch (Exception e){
       //This Exception gets thrown and caught. However the log message never prints.
       //Further along in the code, I get a NullPointerException because
       //the variable 'current' was null and therefore I can't call current.getId()
       //(which is why the log message never printed).
       //but how could current be null when 'id' is in the Request table?
       Log.error("ID = " + current.getId(), e);
    }
}
```

The helper methods:

```
public <T> Object getObj(Class<T> clazz, Criterion crit) throws Exception {
   Object object = null;
   try {
      object = session.createCriteria(clazz).add(crit).uniqueResult();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new Exception(e);
   }
   return object;
}

public <T> void addObject(T object) throws Exception {
    try {
        Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(object);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

**Some notes:**

- The InvalidRequest object is a Hibernate object and it has a one to
  one foreign key relationship with the Request Object. In other words
  that's why when I created a new InvalidRequest, I passed in the
  Request as a parameter.
- The addObject method uses a Transaction but the getObj doesn't. I don't know if this has any particular significance to my problem, but it's just a note.
- You'll notice that I never used evict() or anything on the Request objects. I think this means Hibernate stores them in the Session cache for a while. Does that make it possible that I ran out of memory? Or would Hibernate automatically clear out the cache for me if it got too large? Either way I don't think this is the problem since my code bombed so quickly, but I am not positive.

Comment: Can you add logging in Catch-block of getObj?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for taking a look. I cannot deploy this again on production for a while (months). It doesn't throw an Exception during testing on any of three test machines. I'm not really sure how to proceed or why Hibernate would throw an Exception when all I'm doing is reading then inserting a (new) object with a FK to the object I read into the DB. In testing, I have only been able to replicate the null pointer exception when I delete the object from the database after its already been added to the idList. However this doesn't happen on production; we don't delete from that table.

Comment: Are you sure that id is unique?

Comment: @Andrew yeah, it's the primary key on the table

Comment: How many threads use a session from db? It can be concurrency issue

Comment: @Andrew Only one thread - the thread running the code shown above - uses the InvalidRequest table (that I'm writing to). Lots of threads use the Request table, but the thread I showed above only reads from it, not writes to it, so I don't see how there could be a contention issue, do you?

Comment: The session object is not threadsafe.

Comment: @Andrew that's not the problem though. like I said the session is created in the code above, which resides in its own thread. the session isn't shared.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one, but as I stumble upon it and imo it is still un open issue of Hibernate 3.

Projection in hibernate criteria is incompatible with LockMode,
see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3313
so check your code you probably have

```
criteria.setLockMode(your lock mode)
```

If like us you use some generic code to initialize your criteria here our code extract to deal with this issue

```
CriteriaImpl critiml = (CriteriaImpl) crit;
if (critiml.getProjection() != null) {
    // lock mode is not compatible with projection criteria 
    // see bug entry https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3313
} else {
    crit.setLockMode("obj", LockMode.NONE);
}
```